# How to disable this weird see through

Tags: retopology

I am doing retopology, messing up with settings, but now when I try to edit legs or ear, and I can't see where the mesh is so it become confusing. Backface culling is on, object viewport is set to In front[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are saying is that while you edit the "green" lower density mesh, you want to see the vertices or more detail of the higher detail (horse) mesh?   So you want to control how individual objects are displayed, instead of everything the the viewport (selected and unselected)

You can select the higher detail mesh, an use the Viewport display options to show different details of that mesh before selecting the lower detail mesh and Edit Mode.  "Display As" select: "Wire" may be what you want.  Or you can change Vewport Display options on your lower detail mesh to see through it at times.

Here I have selected that higher detail (sphere) and added "WireFrame":

[image]

Comment: It's much easier now, thanks!